# Enabling tag combination synonyms

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

I've been wondering about the tag synonyms system - the mechanism seems quite robust, but I'm missing the ability to define a relation between tag A and a combination of tags B+C. A sort of one-to-many / many-to-one synonym mapping. Couldn't find this discussed anywhere here.

For example, we have the [graph-algorithm](/questions/tagged/graph-algorithm) tag, which is often useful but not extremely common, and then there are also his older brothers [graph](/questions/tagged/graph) and [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm). Either of them alone is not the same thing of course, but shouldn't questions marked with the combination of both pop out when we search for the [graph-algorithm](/questions/tagged/graph-algorithm)?

And on the other hand - shouldn't questions marked as [graph-algorithm](/questions/tagged/graph-algorithm) get displayed when searching for either [graph](/questions/tagged/graph) or [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm) alone? Or perhaps only when doing a combined search somehow?

This could be pretty useful, especially given the limit on tags. Would love to hear your opinions, maybe it's just over-engineering this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any hierarchical requests for the tag system have always been turned down *in extremis*.

What you have to do is either search for all 3 tags, the default is AND searching:

> **[graph] [algorithm] [graph-algorithm]**

or you can OR search:

> **[graph] OR [algorithm] OR [graph-algorithm]**

Comment: That's really a pain. The amount you need to search for is O(n!) when it should be just O(n)

Comment: I'm using AND/OR searches, but this doesn't help against unknown combinations, not to mention it explodes the length of the search string. I wonder why there's such an objection.